# Obj-c initWithCoder seems to crash NavigationController

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, archive

does anyone know why when i add...

```
-(id) initWithCoder: (NSCoder *) decoder {

    OutputDataMutableArray = [[decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"RootViewControllerPostArray"] retain];

    return self;

}
```

to my RootViewController it will not push a new view from a table cell using the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method. This is the line it seems to hang on...

```
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:postController animated:YES];
```

i get no error messages, it just seems to skip it. Unless i take the initWithCoder out and it works fine.

any insight would be appriciated.

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re not calling the superclass’s implementation of `-initWithCoder:`.

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];

    if(self)
    {
        OutputDataMutableArray = [[decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"RootViewControllerPostArray"] retain];
    }

    return self;
}
```

Comment: “to my RootViewController” would seem to imply that the class inherits from UIViewController, no?

Comment: safe assumption in that case :)

Answer (score 0):

Check the log and look for exceptions being thrown causing your code to terminate prematurely.  Or set a break on `NSException` raise.

BTW, you need to be calling `[super init]` in `initWithCoder`: